# Ajax call not updating a value im sending back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

really unsure about this one.

I have a ajax call that loads more data. This works fine, but i am making a feature where the button is removed once there is no more data.

So, on the php page that is loaded... as well as having the data i also have a div that contains the rowcount of the query.

So in the loadmorebuilds.php i have:

```
// a query that just returns a set of results from the DB. These are just echo'd into divs.

<div id='countvar'><?php echo $isMore ?></div>
```

Thats in the php loadmore page.

And then the whole of the ajax call is so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pageIndex = 1;
    $('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
        $('#buildcontainer').imagesLoaded( function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=trending&pageIndex=' + pageIndex,
           success: function(html) {
              var el = jQuery(html);
              var rowCount = $("#countvar").html();

              jQuery("#buildcontainer").append(el).masonry( 'reload' );
              $("#loadmorebuilds-div").stop().fadeOut();
              pageIndex++;
              $("#buildcontainer").masonry();

              alert(rowCount); 

           }

        });

    });

});
});
```

The issue is, i think that

```
var rowCount = $("#countvar").html();
```

is just checking the current document for a div called 'countvar' So even though new divs with this id are being sent back, it is only taking the first one so if that div has a content of '8' i will always be shown that.

My question is...

**How do i check the returned data for the div called 'countvar'?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you observed, you're selecting the element on the page. You need to find the element within the returned html, but to make is an object, create an object to contain it.

```
 success: function(html) {
    var el = $('<div>').html(html);
    var rowCount = el.find("#countvar").html();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Um8pR/2/

Comment: i have tried similar before, but i just get null as the value. However i know there is a value as the div is appended with the other data and it has a value.

Comment: I got it, you have to append the html to the dom first. Answer updated.

Comment: the .detach worked. Ill have a look into that feature and understand it some more. On click (before the ajax call) i detach the countvar div. Then in the ajax call, after the data has been appended, i check the value of the countvar div ON THE PAGE and it seems to work :) Thanks!

Comment: Actually `.remove()` should work, detach does the same but keeps the jQuery events that are bound to any elements.

Comment: @user2921557, I'm an idiot. You don't need to append to the body, it's the putting it inside of a div that does it. See updated answer and fiddle.